# Best way to handle batch during training and inference in Pytorch with GPU

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, pytorch-dataloader

I am learning the best ways to manage batches and other best practices during model training and inference and I have the following question:

- If I have a batch that I move to GPU, should. I move it back to CPU after doing the training? If no, why?

  ```py
  batch, label = batch.to(device), label.to(device)
  model(batch)
  # ..Training pass... 
  batch, label = batch.cpu(), label.cpu()
  ```

  If I cache my data in my `Dataset` class how can I ensure I can reuse the same batches on GPU to avoid transferring from and to CPU multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to move your data back to the cpu. The data allocation on the GPU is handled by PyTorch. You should use a [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) to handle the data loading from the dataset. However, you will have to send the inputs on the GPU yourself: essentially, every time you need to infer some output, you will send your batch and labels to the GPU and compute the result (and loss), that's all.